# SQL Search in JSON values contains word

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to make sort of a search engine that searched through JSON values in my Database.

I have a table with a column called **data** in **data** there is a JSON string, example:

`{"type_geld":"cash","bedrag":15.0,"totaal":8899.0,"reden":"itemshop-bought-item","citizenid":"EHT44095","steamnaam":"Finn"}`

Now I want to search through the key **steamnaam** I am currently using this query:
`` SELECT * FROM logs_1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(lower(`data`), '"finn"', "$.steamnaam") ``

This does give me the rows that contain finn as a value in the **steamname** JSON.
But now I want to also make it check if it's not exactly the same, but almost the same. So basically a LIKE search. Can I achieve this with JSON_CONTAINS or something like that?

So if I type **fin** instead of **finn** I also want it to list the rows because it almost matches **finn**.

I tried a lot of things, but could not figure it out, hope someone has the solution for me! Thank you.

## The solution I found:

Apparently after googling a bit more, I found this query, that exactly does what I want:

`` SELECT * FROM logs_1 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(lower(`data`), "$.steamnaam") LIKE "%fin%" ``

The only concern I have if this will stay fast with a lot of rows..

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM logs_1 
WHERE data->>'$.steamnaam' LIKE '%fin%' /* COLLATE according CI collation */
```